# How do I append some text to a distant txt file via http in Java?

Tags: java, http, outputstream

A text file is located at http://example.com/myText.txt with read and write permissions.

How can I append some line of text on top of it using Java. I see examples with the class OutputStreamWriter but they all use a file as an output. What about http?

(I need the code to be compatible with Java 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic solution to this other than reading the content, appending the line locally, and writing it back with PUT (and that requires that the server supports the PUT method).

Comment: Thanks, so I'll change for a db solution. Just found Orchestra that looks like what I need: https://orchestrate.io/docs/key-value

Answer (score 3):

HTTP in the sense you understand it does not support any write operation of this nature.

There is no clear relationship between a URL and a file on the server; Specifically HTTP GET generally returns you a file-like resource if the URL refers to a web-like server; but the outcomes of HTTP POST are not simply an overwrite of the remote url file they are processed on a case by case basis by the other side.

If this is really what you want I strongly suggest you use FTP which is intended for this purpose.

Comment: And FTP is better than HTTP with respect to this exactly how?

Comment: @Julian FTP supports write access / PUT support is rare

Comment: well, but it doesn't support appending either, right  :-)